# Time Complexity/big o notation for nested loop recursion

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

I am looking at the following code

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean judgeSquareSum(int c) {
        for (long a = 0; a * a <= c; a++) {
            for (long b = 0; b * b <= c; b++) {
                if (a * a + b * b == c)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

the author is stating the time complexity for this code is √c. What i don't understand is how.

So suppose we are giving an example of c=20. then the code will run 15 times however √20=4.47

Comment: What is the question you have? And can you link to the original assignment/homework/article?

Comment: Seems like the code should be close to o(n) in complexity by a taking a quick glance at it. Running sqrt(n) in the outer loop and about sqrt(n) /2 in the inner one

Comment: This is linear, not √. I believe it's √ in the best-case scenario, but it's not the same thing

Comment: @Progman https://leetcode.com/articles/sum-of-square-numbers/

Comment: I was thinking the same thing it looks like it is linear but author was stating sqrt complexity so i thought maybe i have missed something.

Comment: @dev_ios999 The article says it's `O(c)`, so why do you said it's `O(sqrt(c))`?

Comment: @Progman you are right. I misread the statement. "Two loops upto √c" was for each single loop and i thought it was for the whole program.

Comment: Each loop is O(sqrt(n)), and they’re nested, so overall it’s O(sqrt(n) * sqrt(n)) which is O(n)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The given snippet is `O(n)` and `Ω(√n)`, implying the stated time complexity is merely best case.

[image]

**Logarithmized vertical axis*

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to see some actual runs. √c seems to be the best case scenario. I suspect that happens when `a = 0` and `b * b = c`, eliminating the need for multiple runs of the outer loop.

```
prints:
  i =           10      sqrt =      3   runs =            8
  i =          100      sqrt =     10   runs =           11
  i =        1,000      sqrt =     31   runs =          351
  i =       10,000      sqrt =    100   runs =          101
  i =      100,000      sqrt =    316   runs =        4,121
  i =      500,000      sqrt =    707   runs =       71,501
  i =    1,000,000      sqrt =  1,000   runs =        1,001
  i =    5,000,000      sqrt =  2,236   runs =      521,209
  i =   10,000,000      sqrt =  3,162   runs =      382,721
  i =   50,000,000      sqrt =  7,071   runs =    7,079,001
  i =  100,000,000      sqrt = 10,000   runs =       10,001
```

Printed with:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
  static int counter;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(10);
    print(100);
    print(1000);
    print(10000);
    print(100000);
    print(500000);
    print(1000000);
    print(5000000);
    print(10000000);
    print(50000000);
    print(100000000);
  }

  static void print(int i) {
    new Solution().judgeSquareSum(i);
    String format = "  i = %,12d\tsqrt = %,6d\truns = %,12d\n";
    System.out.printf(format,i,(int)Math.sqrt(i),counter);

  }

  static class Solution { // only added a counter
      public boolean judgeSquareSum(int c) {
          counter = 0;
          for (long a = 0; a * a <= c; a++) {
              for (long b = 0; b * b <= c; b++) {
                  counter++;
                  if (a * a + b * b == c)
                      return true;
              }
          }
          return false;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be further optimised to:

```
public boolean judgeSquareSum(final int c) {

    final long rootC = (long) Math.sqrt(c);

    if (c == rootC * rootC) {
        return true;
    }

    for (long a = 0; a <= rootC; a++) {

        final long aSquared = a * a;
        final long b        = (long) Math.sqrt(c - aSquared);

        if (aSquared + b * b == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above produces identical results to the original Posting for all +ve `c`.

Comment: That is **Approach 3** in the [leetcode article](https://leetcode.com/articles/sum-of-square-numbers/#approach-3-using-sqrt-function)

Answer (score -1):

Put another way: if `a² + b² = c`, the limiting case is:

`a² + 0² = c` (& of course 0² + b² = c, which is analagous)
-> `a² =  c`
-> `a  = √c`

So, for any `b`, `a <= √c`

The originally posted code checks `a * a <= c` for every iteration.
It is considered best practice (because its faster) to evaluate limiting values once only.
As we just saw, `a * a <= c` can be rewritten as `a <= √c`

So the for-loop could be coded as follows:

```
final long rootC = (long) Math.sqrt(c);

for (long a = 0; a <= rootC; a++) {
    :
    :
}
```

...which I hope makes the √c complexity claim for the original code clear.

The 2nd for-loop is unnecessary, as `b` can be calculated empirically

For any `a`:
`a² + b² = c` (where `c` is known)
-> `b² =   c - a²`
-> `b  = √(c - a²)`
(only integer values of `b` being acceptable)

Answer (score -5):

Your Max conditions are

```
a * a <= c
```

and

```
b * b <= c
```

If you take the Square Root of both sides you get `a <= √c` & `b <= √c`

So, if you optimise your code for performance...
(i.e. don't calculate the maximum on every iteration!)
...it would look like this:

```
public boolean judgeSquareSum(final int c) {

    final long rootC = (long) Math.sqrt(c);

    for (    long a = 0; a <= rootC; a++) {
        for (long b = 0; b <= rootC; b++) {

            if (a * a + b * b == c) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So now you see where the complexity claim of √c came from.

Comment: But wouldn't that make it `rootC * rootC = c`?

Comment: With nested loops, you multiply the complexities of each loop. _O(√c)_ * _O(√c)_ = _O(√c * √c)_ = _O((√c)²)_ = _O(c)_

Comment: Scratte & Andreas are obviously not Mathematicians. If a * a <= c, then √a <= c for all a >= 0.

Comment: The [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/articles/sum-of-square-numbers/#solution) article even says so: *Time complexity : O(c). Two loops upto √c​. Here, c refers to the given integer(sum of squares).*

Comment: Lets assume that the loops were both `< n`. That would make the complexity `n * n = n²`, right?

Comment: @DaveTheDane *"If a * a <= c, then √a <= c for all a >= 0"* Yes, since `√a <= a * a` for any *integer* value `a`, but what does that have to do with anything? Outer loop is _O(√c)_. Inner loop is _O(√c)_ by itself, so inner loop inside outer loop is _O(√c * √c)_ = _O(c)_. I'm not a pro mathematician, but I do know basic Big-O math like that.